# How would you translate "running/operating a nonprofit program" to Russian?

Tags: перевод

Trying to translate a non-profit document into Russian and run into this challenge. All the translations I seem to find on the internet concern computer programs rather than programmatic activities by nonprofits. Also, "Вести программу" doesn't seem quite right. Any suggestions?

Here's the full sentence:

> We may be required to collect some personal information by law or by organizations that give us money to operate this program. Other personal information that we collect is important to run our programs, to improve services, and to better understand the needs of our clients.

Comment: Проводить программу? Please provide a broader context... before you get shot down by the moderator... quick! ;)

Comment: This question looks fine to me as it is

Comment: Still, some more context wouldn't hurt. At least the full sentence rather than just a 'naked' phrase.

Comment: I also wouldn’t dare to say anything without context. How many definitions of ‘run’ are in dictionaries? Tens or hundreds. The same is with ‘get’, ‘have’ and ‘take’.

Comment: Just added context. I think that курировать is a great option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is *курировать*, as in *курировать программу НКО*.

> В 1995 году сотрудничает с НДР: сначала создает инфраструктуру движения, потом курирует программу помощи кандидатам от НДР в одномандатных округах. // *[ Алексей Головков // «Итоги», 1996.09.03]*

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot.